# Getting a variable out of a Public Void (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, variables, media-player

I have this code:

```
    hubSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
      final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(Textbox.this, R.raw.hero);
      mp2.start();
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        }
    });
```

(The code basically runs when a new item is selected of a spinner and then plays a song, which later will be a variable based on what was picked, but I'm fine as it is for now).

Problem: I want to be able to use 'mp2' out of this public void, (I want a button which pauses it). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the variable `mp2` to the instance of the parent class. This will keep a running reference to it which you can interact with whenever you please. You will need to remove the `final` qualifier though if `MediaPlayer.create(...)` will be called more than once and stored.

---

edit:

I was referring to something along the lines of this:

```
class SomeClass {
    private MediaPlayer mp2 = null;

    private void whateverFunctionYouAreIn() {
        hubSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                SomeClass.this.mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(Textbox.this, R.raw.hero);
                SomeClass.this.mp2.start();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}
        });

        //TODO: put this in an onClickListener:
        if (this.mp2 != null) {
            this.mp2.pause();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need it inside... (For reasons put on the comment on Chris's answer)

Comment: See my edit. Exactly the same as your code except you are storing the `MediaPlayer` object in the main class instance.

Comment: So then I just put the (pause) button in the 'Some Class' -but not in the private void? -and it will work?

Comment: You can put the pause stuff anywhere you'd like. I assume you are doing all this in the `onCreate` method (if I remember correctly) so when you do `pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { ... });` put the `TODO` section in there.

Comment: Ok yeah I think that is working, except one problem, it doesnt run atall, -no music is ever played so i'm thinking there is a problem with the private function, 'private void whateverFunctionYouAreIn() {
' -Does that run with/by itself? or what?  -or the class? is that being called -or does it not need too?

Comment: No. You should put it in the `onCreate` method (or whichever method you were originally placing your original code snippet).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happens when you call `MediaPlayer.create(Textbox.this, R.raw.hero)`, but assuming it has no immediate effects, you can just create the object outside of the listener.

---

Edit1: OK, then how about this?

```
MediaPlayer currentPlayer;

methodA()
{
   hubSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
   {
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
             View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
       {
          MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(Textbox.this, R.raw.hero);
          mp2.start();
          setPlayer(mp2);
       }
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    }
});


setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayer player)
{
   currentPlayer = player;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know, but as I said in future (after fixing this problem) i am going to use 'R.raw.****Variable value from spinner*****' instead -to find the mp3 track. -So it can't go outside, -or can it? :)

Comment: I don't know where R.raw comes from unfortunately, I have no Android experience, but it doesn't sound like a local variable, so you could probably put it anywhere you want.